How do I define a type which is already available globally?
I am using react with vite.js, I have typescript setup too, I have installed Jimp which is mainly made for node.js but has a minified script that you can load, I have loaded it in main.jsx like this:
...
import "jimp/browser/lib/jimp";
...

I am able to access it using window.Jimp or Jimp, it has same interface as import Jimp from "jimp" so I wanna declare Jimp as a global variable/constant as Jimp type, how do I do that? I have tried the following inside src/types/global.d.ts but did not work:
import Jimp from "jimp";

declare global {
  const Jimp: typeof Jimp;
}


My configurations:
tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}

tsconfig.app.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}

tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

I also have this .eslintrc.cjs:
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ["dist", ".eslintrc.cjs"],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  plugins: ["react-refresh"],
  rules: {
    "react-refresh/only-export-components": [
      "warn",
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
  },
}

Thanks!
EDIT:
Looks like I need to invoke ESLint: Restart ESLint Server command to see the changes on vscode, now it shows Jimp like this:


For example: I have svg.d.ts and tsconfig.json.
In svg.d.ts:
declare module "*.svg" {
  import * as React from "react";

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
    React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string }
  >;
}


In tsconfigs.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "types": ["vitest/globals", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "svg.d.ts"]
}


You can try to edit "include": ["src", "xxx.d.ts"] in your tsconfig.app.json
It's working for me, hope can help you :)

Thanks for recommendation but unfortunately it did not work, also check my edit on my post. Thanks!
